# What does "Unable to create o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool" mean?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven

I get this error when running app:

> main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create
>   initial connections of pool.

The first java error is here:

> java.sql.SQLException: null
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:323)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]

I have added dependency to postgres in my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I dont really understand the error. What is wrong here? 
Details: 
Spring-boot app deployed to remote server.
         Installed psql database
         OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Here is postgres connection file:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypass

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: can you provide more stacktrace ?

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3in2o Full stacktrace pasted inside the link.

Comment: What is the name of your "postgres connection file:" ?

Comment: application.properties placed under src\main\resources

Comment: In your stacktrace, it seems like you are running your tests. How do you run them ? If you run without maven, do you have a different output ? Can you please be more descriptive ? I know what is causing your error.. If you go far into the postgresql jar, you find out that, somehow, postgreqsl can't get the dbname... I'm trying to know why.

Comment: Im trying to build a deployable web app. I use $ mvn clean install.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206496/discussion-between-ruaro-thibault-and-sampo-kaarenmaa).